# Different data type for JSON array based whether Debug=True/False in Django Rest API and Django-admin

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-2.0

I'm using Django's wonderful select2 drop-down within the Admin interface to trigger a custom jQuery AJAX GET request to a DRF endpoint to attempt to populated a list of inlines based on a Foreign key relation. However, when I test this within production (Debug=False) in settings.py it returns the data as Array() object rather just a regular JSON Object whenever I preform the same request in development (Debug=True).

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Machine Cleaned drop-down box, Equipment cleaning log.

    //// Hides the 'Add more' row for the Cleaning Entry table
    $('table.cleaning-table tbody tr.add-row').remove();

    row_container = $(
        '<tr class="form-row dynamic-log_entry row1" id="log_entry-0">'+
        '<td class="original"><input type="hidden" name="log_entry-0-id" id="id_log_entry-0-id">'+
        '<input type="hidden" name="log_entry-0-log_entry" id="id_log_entry-0-log_entry"></td>'+
        '<td class="field-cleaning_item"><input type="text" name="log_entry-0-cleaning_item" class="vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField" id="id_log_entry-0-cleaning_item">'+
        '<a href="/admin/quality/equipmentaction/?_to_field=id" class="related-lookup" id="lookup_id_log_entry-0-cleaning_item" title="Lookup"></a></td>'+
        '<td class="field-cleaning_action"><input type="text" name="log_entry-0-cleaning_action" disabled="" id="id_log_entry-0-cleaning_action" style="width: 200px;"></td>'+
        '<td class="field-checked"><input type="checkbox" name="log_entry-0-checked" id="id_log_entry-0-checked"></td>'+
        '<td class="field-na"><input type="checkbox" name="log_entry-0-na" id="id_log_entry-0-na"></td>'+
        '<td class="field-grade"><select name="log_entry-0-grade" id="id_log_entry-0-grade">'+
            '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'+
            '<option value="A">A - Pharmaceutical</option>'+
            '<option value="B">B - Satisfactory</option>'+
            '<option value="C">C - Unsatisfactory</option>'+
            '<option value="D">D - N/A</option></select></td>'+
        '<td class="field-notes"><input type="text" name="log_entry-0-notes" maxlength="512" id="id_log_entry-0-notes" class="vTextField"></td>'+
        '<td class="delete"></td></tr>'
    );

    //// This binds an ".on(select)" event function to the select2 box for the machine_used that
    //// preforms an AJAX call using the machine_fk reference id to get all the EquipmentActions
    //// records for that machine using REST API.
    $("select#id_machine_used").on("select2:select", function(event) {
        machine_fk = event.params.data.id;
        $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType:'json',
        url:'http://192.168.254.13:8888/pyscales/v1/quality/?machine_fk='+machine_fk,
        //Upon a successful GET request, data is returned in JSON form.
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(data.results).each(function (i, item) {
                // console.log(i, item);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
})(django.jQuery);
```

I do not understand what would cause this, other than possibly a conflict with jQuery libraries between production & development but I'm using Whitenoise & Gunicorn to server the static files from the same folder for Django. The only difference I can see is that in production jquery.min.js gets loaded instead of the regular jquery.js file, which is expected.
As a side note, I have also tried adding my custom script to the Media class within the admin and instead decided to hardcode is via a  tag within and overridden admin template instead.

It seems there are many ways to get this done but I'm fairly new to jQuery and AJAX so I get the feeling like I'm missing something simple or not following a 'best practice' method. I know there's a lot of variables to this so if I need to post something else please let me know. Any help would be insanely appreciated, you high-level stack guys are my heroes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a lesson for future viewers and newcomers to Django/DRF and/or jQuery, always follow the data back to it's source when there's a change in types and closely examine subtle changes in arrays when dealing with JSON.

In trying to follow "best practices" I had 2 settings.py files: settings_dev.py and settings_prod.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
}
```

One contained code for pagination in DRF and one did not. Thus resulting in two different JSON arrays being return base on which settings.py file I chose...

```
//Production - w/o pagination

[
    {
        "id": 59,
        "item_fk_id": 1,
        "item_fk": "TEST1",
        "action": "TEST ACTION!"
    }
]

//Development with paging
{
    "count": 6,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 59,
            "item_fk_id": 1,
            "item_fk": "TEST1",
            "action": "TEST ACTION!"
        }
    ]
```